# Problem using "set" with Sprout SEO

Tags: templating, plugin-sproutseo

I usually use `{% block %}{% endblock %}` to build my template but for the [SEO plugin](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/seo/docs/examples/extending-a-base-layout) I'll be needing `{% set %}{% endset %}`. However my pages don't seem to render. If I change it to `{% block %}{% endblock %}` it works fine.

Anyone know what is causing this?

This is my base file _master.html (partly):

```
<body class="boxed bg-cover" style="background-image: url(img/backgrounds/street.jpg)">
 <div class="global-wrap">
     {% set header %}
     {% endset %}
```

this is my index.html (partly):

```
{% extends "_master" %}
 {% set header %}
   {% include 'header.html' %}
 {% endset %}
```

Comment: can you show your code?

Comment: I edited the post. Its pretty straightforward.

Comment: You'll need to print the header variable after setting, ie {{ header }}

Comment: Are you sure that the SEO plugin isn't working when you use `block`? That's largely a formatting preference... Templates render from the inside-out, so your `do` would still get called before anything in the master template.

Comment: I got a bit thrown off by this --> Note: In our examples we have chosen to use the {% set %} tag to build our layouts because it gets processed in the same way as all of the other Twig tags - from top to bottom. The {% block %} tag, while useful for many use cases in your templates, does not get processed until last, so we’re unable to update our meta data using craft.sproutSeo.meta() in a {% block %} tag because our craft.sproutSeo.optimize() tag gets processed before the {% block %} tag runs.

Comment: Ah, interesting. I didn't catch that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that's just the way they have set up the templates in the example, so what you're doing is just fine (using `{% block %}`), if that's how your templates are set up.

The difference is by using `{% set %}` you are just setting your content to a variable which would be `{{ echoed }}` into the layout file that you extend. Whereas using `{% block %}` you are telling twig what block of content should be inherited into the layout you are extending.

The twig docs probably explain it better:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/extends.html
http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html

From the looks of it with the plugin in question, providing you add `{{ craft.sproutSeo.optimize() }}` into your layout template you should be all good to go.

#### Example with `{% set %}`

**_layout.html**

```
<body>
  {{ content }}
</body>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends '_layout' %}

{% set content %}
 Some content
{% endset %}
```

#### Example with `{% block %}`

**_layout.html**

```
<body>
  {% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends '_layout' %}

{% block content %}
 Some content
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: thanks. Ill think in my case block will just be fine indeed.